# CustomController class as CustomCell in SensibleTableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview, frameworks, nsuserdefaults

I currently use the Sensible TableView Framework to create a search filter mask for a new app.
All works fine, but the latest Screendesign offers new problems.

It's now required to select a range between a min and a max value. Instead of using two numeric textfields to define the range, we now have to create a new type of custom RangeSlider (familiar to the UISliderView). For now I created the RangeSlider (Slider with two thumbmarks) as CustomClass, without xib file. I now have to implement this in my tableview as customCell?
Still can't figure out how to do this via STV.

My RangeSlider needs some properties to be set:

- float minimumValue;
- float maximumValue;
- float minimumRange;
- float selectedMinimumValue;
- float selectedMaximumValue;

and responds to the user interaction by changing the properties values.

[image: Range Slider: That's how it looks like.]

My problem in short:
How to implement my RangeSlider Class as CustomCell, without xib file?
And.. is it possible to track the userInteraction of my customCell with SCUserDefaultsDefinition,too?

**That's the way I create my STV:**

```
SCUserDefaultsDefinition *userDefaultsDef = [SCUserDefaultsDefinition definitionWithDictionaryKeyNamesString:@"Search Filter:(gender,ageRangeSlider,zip,country)"];
SCPropertyDefinition *genderDef = [userDefaultsDef propertyDefinitionWithName:@"gender"];
genderDef.title = @"Gender";
genderDef.required = TRUE;
genderDef.type = SCPropertyTypeSelection;
genderDef.attributes = [SCSelectionAttributes attributesWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"f", @"m", nil] allowMultipleSelection:NO allowNoSelection:NO];
genderDef.autoValidate = TRUE;

/*#### CUSTOMCELL IMPLEMENTATION HERE #### */

SCPropertyDefinition *zip = [userDefaultsDef propertyDefinitionWithName:@"zip"];
zip.title = @"Zip-Code";
zip.type = SCPropertyTypeNumericTextField;
zip.attributes = [SCNumericTextFieldAttributes attributesWithMinimumValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:01] maximumValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:99] allowFloatValue:NO];
[self.tableViewModel generateSectionsForUserDefaultsDefinition:userDefaultsDef];
SCTableViewSection *formSection = [self.tableViewModel sectionAtIndex:0];
formSection.cellActions.valueChanged = ^(SCTableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
{
     NSLog(@"\n\n*********** Key Binding Log ***********\n");
     NSLog(@"Value: %@\n", [cell boundValue]);
};
```

Would be great if somebody could help!
I really appreciate that! Please tell me if you need more information.

Thanks,

Lars
(sry for my bad english )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, problem solved!

**Here comes the solution:**
To add a customClass as CustomCell in STV, you have to define a SCCustomPropertyDefinition using the Classname/Nibname and the tag of your customControl as objectBinding.

```
SCUserDefaultsDefinition *userDefaultsDef = [SCUserDefaultsDefinition definitionWithDictionaryKeyNamesString:@"Search Filter:(gender,ageRangeSlider,zip,country)"];

SCCustomPropertyDefinition * customControl = [SCCustomPropertyDefinition definitionWithName:@"ageRangeSlider" uiElementClass:[CustomControlClass class] objectBindingsString:@"1:selectedRange;"];
[userDefaultsDef insertPropertyDefinition:customControl atIndex:1];
```

After creating and adding the new PropertyDefinition to your UserDefaultsDefinition, you can use the ObjectBindingString from the PropertyDefinition (@"1:selectedRange;") to configure the Response Property in your CustomControlClass.
The number presents the IB Tag for each control in the custom cell, while the String stands for the Property to use as ResponseValue for this Control.

Hope this may help other Devs in future.